# anonymous thread with parameter in lazarus

Tags: multithreading, pascal, lazarus

i cant pass parameter withe the anonimous tread in lazarus
i used a delphi examples but they dosn't work

```
procedure hi(i:integer);
begin
   form1.caption:=inttostr(i);
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  for i:=1 to 4 do
  TThread.CreateAnonymousThread(
      TProcedure(@hi(i));
  ).Start;

end;
```

i tried this example it dosn't work

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Thread: TThread;
  Value: Integer;
begin
  Value := 42;
  Thread := TThread.CreateAnonymousThread(
    procedure
    begin
      hi('hello');
    end
  );

  Thread.Start;
end;
```